# Proportional sizing using equal heights missing constraint

Tags: autolayout, proportions

I would like the blue container view to be the same height as the orange container view. I am using proportional sizing to do so (all of these are within a vertical stack)I selected all of the containers then added the equal heights constraint to them. I am confused because there does not seem to be a proportional height constraint for the blue container view. I was able to change the proportional heights of the others just fine.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Change the names of all your `Container View` instances ... ***very, very*** difficult to tell which one is related to which other one.

Comment: Oops sorry about that! I just renamed and reposted.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout is exactly what you've specified for the Heights:

```
Orange: 0.5 * Blue (1/2 Blue Height)
Green:  == Blue
Yellow: == Blue
Purple: == Blue
Grey:   0.5 * Blue (1/2 Blue Height)
```

If you want *"the blue container view to be the same height as the orange container view"*, you need to set

```
Orange: == Blue
Green:  == Blue
Yellow: == Blue
Purple: == Blue
Grey:   0.5 * Blue (1/2 Blue Height)
```

You do not set a "proportional height" constraint on the Blue Container itself, because you've already told the stack view to fit all the views based on those Height constraints.

---

**Edit** - in response to comment: *"I would like the blue itself to be smaller like the orange appears"*

If you write this out (or speak it), you can probably answer the question yourself...

I want :

- orange.height equal to blue.height
- grey.height equal to blue.height
- green.height twice as tall as blue.height
- yellow.height twice as tall as blue.height
- purple.height twice as tall as blue.height

So...

```
Orange: == Blue
Grey:   == Blue
Green:  == Blue * 2.0
Yellow: == Blue * 2.0
Purple: == Blue * 2.0
```

Maybe this will help you understand...

We don't assign a Height to the Blue view, because we are using the Height of the stack view to arrange its subviews.

So, let's assume the stack view Height is 450-points, either by setting it or by setting Top and Bottom constraints - and it just happens to be 450 because it will give this example nice numbers.

If we have Two views - Blue and Orange - and we want them the same Height, it looks like this:

[image]

Very simplified, auto-layout says: *"Blue has a Height of **1 unit**, Orange is equal to Blue, so it also has a Height of **1 unit**. 1 + 1 == 2, for a total of 2 Height units, so divide 450 by 2 and give each view a height of 225"*

If we want Orange to be twice as tall as Blue, we constrain `Orange.Height = Blue.Height with Multiplier: 2` and we get this:

[image]

Auto-layout says: *"Blue has a Height of **1 unit**, Orange is equal to Blue x 2, so it has a Height of **2 units**. 1 + 2 == 3 total Height units... `450 / 3 == 150`, so give Blue a Height of `1 x 150 == 150` and give Orange a Height of `150 x 2 == 300`"*.

For your layout, it looks like this:

[image]

We now have a total of **9 Height units** (`1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 1`), and auto-layout says: *"`450 / 9 == 50` (per Height unit) ..."* and you can see how it lays out the views.

Comment: Thanks.. that does make the orange container the same height as the blue but I would like the blue itself to be smaller like the orange appears. Is there a way to do so? Or do I need to start over and make the blue container have a height constraint to start with and then fit all the views based on that somehow?

Comment: @Summer - see the **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: Thank you!! You made it where my artist brain could understand it... much appreciated!! :) One of the most clear answers I have seen on here!